# Run some unit tests twice in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a straightforward unit test class like so:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class SomeTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // make some assertions
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test2()
        {
            // make some assertions
        }
        // ...
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test50()
        {
            // make some assertions
        }
    }
```

and I basically want to run Test1..Test50 twice via the "Run All" command. Once with App.config like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeSetting" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

and once with App.config like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeSetting" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Being lazy, I don't want to refactor & parameterize 50 tests. And obviously I don't want 50 duplicate tests.

I'm having a bit of a brain fart over this, apologies if it's blindingly obvious.

Comment: If you're executing it using Visual Studio GUI I don't find the issue because you can run twice by just clicking *Run all* once it finishes the first test run :\

Comment: May I ask what benefits you get if you run it twice?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - but that would require manually altering the App.config file every time I wanted to run the test, correct? I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - the setting completely changes the implementation used by the tests.

Comment: @sming Manually? You're wrong. Do you know about configuration transformations? It would be changing the build configuration (Debug A to Debug B) in the VS drop-down and go

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer No, I didn't know about that feature. However ideally there'd just be one button-click to test both configurations.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer damn straight ^_^  Seriously though, I know I will forget to run both configurations at some point.

Comment: @sming Probably you'll solve your issue implementing a VS extension which might run focused test project twice

Answer (score 1):

make SomeTests abstract.

Add two new projects, with the two different .config files.

In each project add a TestClass that inherits from SomeTests.

Run all will now run both sets of tests.

Answer (score 0):

Create two Test Settings. Click Enable Deployment under the Deployment section. Add your two different App.Config files (one to each Test Settings). Execute your tests, then swap to the other TestSettings and execute them again.

Might be a way to run with all testsettings, but I haven't found it.

Comment: thanks, sounds reasonable. I can see how to select an existing Test Settings file but cannot see where I can create Test Settings.

Comment: Ah, I suspect your using VS.net 2012+. The Test Settings file has been replaced by a similar .RunSettings file. Instructions are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj635153.aspx

Comment: thanks @PhillipH. How/where can I set an <appSettings> setting though? I don't see a way to point to different App.config files or override the <appSettings>.

Comment: Ahh, curse you Microsoft. The setting for Deployment previously available in .TestSettings is not available in the new .RunSettings. You can still use .TestSettings by right-clicking your test solutuon and adding a new TestSettings file. The properties of TestSettings includes the ability to add files to the test deployment - here is where your two TestSettings would deploy different versions of your app.config; alternatively specify a Setup Script to manipulate the XML of your existing app.config.

Comment: thanks @PhillipH, much appreciated. Like you lament, this should be easy!